# Unable to display image in React Native using Image component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm facing an issue with displaying images in my React Native app using the `Image` component. I have the following code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/image.jpg' }}
        style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

However, the image is not showing up on the screen. I have verified that the image URL is correct. Am I missing something in my code, or is there a common mistake that could be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Feel free to customize it based on your specific situation or add more details if needed.

Comment: The code you've shared looks structurally correct for displaying an image in a React Native app . Are you testing on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/show-image).

- Add `flex:1`or `style={{width: 100, height: 100}}` to Image
- Ensure that the parent view were shown

```js
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#ff00ff'}}>
      <Image style={{flex: 1}} source={{uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/homepage/phones.png'}} />
    </View>
  );
}
```